# PowerBI counts rows in non related table including filtering and non-matches

Tags: join, count, powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have two tables in PowerBI and a slicer, presented below in an abstracted way.

[image: Table Layout]

I want to know the number of orders placed for a customer in a given date range. This data is a sample for illustration - there are actually around 10,000 Customers and 500,000 Orders and both tables have many other fields, Ids etc.

**My challenge** - 
Whilst this is easy enough do by relating the tables and doing a count, the difficulty comes in when I still want to see customers with 0 orders and on top of that I want this to work within a date range. In other words, instead of the customers with no orders disappearing form the list, I want them to appear in the list, but with a 0 value, depending on the date range. It would also be good if this could act as a measure, so I can see the number of total customers that have not ordered on a month by month basis. I have tried outer joins, merge queries, cross joins and lookups and cant seem to crack it.

*Example 1:* If I set the order date slicer to be: 02/01/2017 to 01/01/2018 I want the following results

[image: Ex1]

*Example 2:* If I set the order date slicer to be:  03/01/2017 to 06/01/2017 I want the following results

[image: Ex2]

Any help appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: If I showed all the attempts there would be another few pages of screen shots which would muddy the question. Your suggestion will not work, since the date filter is on the orders and it will exclude the 0 items, instead of showing them with a 0 value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is entirely possible with a Measure. When you're using the Order field to count the rows for each customer, you're essential doing a `COUNTROWS()` function.

With your relationship still active, we can Prefix this in a measure to check for the blanks, and in those cases, return 0. something like this would work

```
Measure = IF(ISBLANK(COUNTROWS(Orders)),0,COUNTROWS(Orders))
```

In this case, `'Orders'`  is the table containing the `Order` and `Order Date` fields

Comment: After kicking myself for a few minutes for not considering ISBLANK(), I came to the conclusion that you are a genius :) - thanks! Now to determine how to represent that as a monthly value (customers who never ordered in a month).